# iOS Notification Rate Filter

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm looking for a way to put a filter on the rate of notifications iOS sends for an app.  For instance say I have the google hangouts app with a group chat of ~10 people and someone is replying every few seconds.  What I want is a setting where I can limit how often it sends me a notification, or even just how often the notifications cause the phone to buzz.  If I could have a single notification for any amount of activity on an app over the course of maybe 5 minutes that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can set a rate filter, but this is something that could be suggested to the developers! :)

You can also just turn off/configure notifications for that app differently so it stops bugging you.

Comment: I just submitted a feature request via the bug reporter - thanks.

Comment: You're most certainly welcome! Thanks for marking this as the correct answer. :)